# How to change link of more button under tabs

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have 4 tabs menu

```
<ul id="get_link">
   <li class="active"><a href="/latest-movies">Latest</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($year);?>">New Movies</a></li>
   <li><a href="/coming-soon">Coming Soon</a></li>
   <li><a href="/hd-movies">HD Movies</a></li>
</ul>
```

and more button

```
<a class="showMore" id="more_linkz" href="/latest-movies">more »</a>
```

I want to change/update more button link when i click on tab menu.For example: when i click on `HD Movies` i want  this link in more button also

I do research and code this but it's not working good i have check this code and alert address value it show the links of tabs in alert but not putting in More button.

```
<script>
        $('ul#get_link li a').click(function () {
                var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
                $("a#more_linkz").attr("href", addressValue);
        });

 </script>
```

Comment: if possible can you add working fiddle example ?

Comment: it seems it is fine do check

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Unless your link will be redirect.

Comment: dose your page reload or redirect ?

Comment: here is jsfiddle and it's not working well :( please help https://jsfiddle.net/3vqzmcL6/

Comment: yes more button refresh with ajax

Comment: When i click on tab menu it's reload Script and More Buton because More button is in the block of ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking your code, there is nothing wrong with that. Unless when clicked into link, it will redirect that make your script can't be read. You need to put  `e.preventDefault();` to avoid from being redirect.

```
    $('ul#get_link li a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
            $("a#more_linkz").attr("href", addressValue);
    });
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4zjrd0s/1/). Try to inspect element on more link, then click any of tab link and see the href attribute actually changed.

Comment: it's not working i think When i click on tab menu it's reload Script and More Buton because More button is in the block of ajax

Comment: If that case, you need to use event delegation for dynamic content